# Kernel: Right way to check if process is running in c

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to check if a process which pid I have is running from an kernel extension.

In user-space this would be simple:

```
if (kill(pid, 0) == 0) {
printf("Process %d is running\n", pid);
} else if (errno == ESRCH) {
printf("Process %d is not running\n", pid);
} else {
printf("This shouldn't happen oO\n");
```

But somehow kill() is not available in kernel. Is there another approach to do this?

Comment: In a way yes but I think Christophe answer and my snippet could be helpful for other users

Comment: This question will remain linked to the duplicate, so people can see your answers and the question, should the question be closed as a duplicate.  Don't be dis-heartened if it is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pid_task()` or `get_pid_task()` to get a pointer to the `struct task_struct` of the process. If the call returns `NULL` then the process does not exist.

Note that you may need to be careful as the *pid* might have been recycled and is now used by a different process.

Answer (score 4):

After Christophe's answer I found the a way to solve this.

```c
//necessary imports
#include <linux/sched.h> 
#include <linux/pid.h> 
//Rest of your module
pid_t pid = myPid; //integer value of pid
struct pid *pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid); //function to find the pid_struct
struct task_struct *task = pid_task(pid_struct,PIDTYPE_PID); //find the task_struct

if (task == NULL)
{
    printk (KERN_INFO "Process with pid %d is not running \n",argument);
}
else{
    printk (KERN_INFO "Process with pid %d is running \n",argument);
}
```

Comment: In your `else`-block the `task` pointer could became invalid (freed). And if the `argument` assumes `task->pid` (dereference) - it could be **use-after-free BUG**. `pid_task()` should be used inside RCU critical section.